# What is the reference in Vāstusūtra Upaniṣad which mentions significance of Murthi worship?

Tags: upanishads, idols

I came accross an [answer on Quora](https://qr.ae/pGmi0j) regarding Vāstusūtra Upaniṣad that it mentiones the significance of Murthi (or idol) worship as an inducive step in making a devotee contemplate about the formless Brahman—which is the ultimate goal of a Murthi. But, I'd like to know the exact reference in the Vāstusūtra Upaniṣad which mentions this.

Thanks.